# Timelike completelness Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Let M be an timelike geodesically complete Lorentizian manifold and $v$ unit timelike vector field. I think that that the flow $F_t$ of this vector field is defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true? Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that a Lorentz manifolds is timelike geodesically complete when all timelike geodesic of $M$ is defined for all values of the parameter t. But i don't know if the flow of every vector field timelike is defined for $t\in \mathbb{R}$.